# Does Heroku support `rails dbconsole`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to fire up `rails dbconsole` on Heroku but get the following error:

```
heroku run rails dbconsole
# => Couldn't find database client: psql. Check your $PATH and try again
```

Is it possible to use the dbconsole on Heroku? If not is there another client that can be used?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql - "You must have PostgreSQL installed on your system to use heroku pg:psql". So maybe you're missing PostgreSQL on your machine. If that's not the case, then try this other command to get to the Postgres console instead:

```
heroku pg:psql
```

"psql is the native PostgreSQL interactive terminal and is used to execute queries and issue commands to the connected database."

Comment: Weird, about a year ago I was able to use
     heroku run rails dbconsole
on all my machines, now it says # => Couldn't find database client: psql. Check your $PATH and try again
Of course I have psql in my PATH, what's more, adding PATH=/usr/local/bin to heroku command didn't help

Answer (score 8):

I think [heroku-sql-console](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console) should provide similar functionality, but when I tried running it I got this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `app' for # (NameError)
```

It's been [reported as a bug](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console/issues/11) but there's no fix or workaround.

Update: As @Alban suggests, the fix to this problem is to update the client. I had to run `gem update heroku` to do this.

Comment: Heroku now says this is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

As Luke says, you may use [heroku-sql-console](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console). But first make sure you are using the latest heroku client:

```
> heroku update
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use the dbconsole on Heroku? If not is there another client that can be used?

You can use online database client if you use `activeadmin`.

Just add the gem [activeadmin-sqlpage](https://github.com/oklas/activeadmin-sqlpage):

```
gem 'activeadmin-sqlpage'
```

And create activeadmin page:

```
# file app/admin/sql.rb
ActiveAdmin::SqlPage::register
```

Restart your server. Then go to admin panel and navigate the menu `SQL`. Enter any sql command and press `Ctrl+Enter` or `Submit` button.