# Getting an error with heroku rails, Couldn't find database client psql. Check your $PATH and try again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Trying to do a database operation that requires me to do `rails db`

I'm doing `heroku run rails db` but I'm getting

`Running`rails db`attached to terminal... up, run.7334
Couldn't find database client: psql. Check your $PATH and try again.`

I have done:

```
gem update heroku
```

but it didn't help.  Still getting the same error.

Also:

```
$ heroku run bundle exec rails db --account work --app dmplanning
Running `bundle exec rails db` attached to terminal... up, run.1572
Couldn't find database client: psql. Check your $PATH and try again.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143488/does-heroku-support-rails-dbconsole

Comment: those answers didn't help unfortunately, I tried them.

Comment: Any luck with this yet? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Please see my answer below.  Perhaps it will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These work:

```
heroku pg:psql --app # From the app's root directory
heroku pg:psql --app your_app_name # specifying the app
heroku pg:psql --app your_app_name --account work 
                   # if you have multiple accounts, specify which one.
```